# Sound wave "lost" with certain distortion level

Tags: waves, acoustics

Can anyone explain how, say,  a guitar note,  can get "lost" in the mix of instruments at a high distortion level,  but not at a lower one.  I believe it's related to the change in the sound wave,  but why would that change if it is the same note?

Comment: Do you know what "distortion" means at a mathematical or physical level? In other words, when we say that mix has distortion, do you know what that actually means for the sound signal?

Comment: DanielSank, if I remember correctly,  distortion of a sound wave here means causing breaks in the wave,  but keeping the same shape.   I would like to know the true answer to that at a physical and mathematical level,  if someone could explain that part.   Thanks for breaking it down.

Comment: Senor O's answer more or less explains it, but let us know if you need more information.

Comment: Just would love another example of a square wave,  I have not heard of that.   Also,  what, or where the "attack" would be on the sine audio wave.   I'm guessing the very first sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question but I'm not entirely sure that your claim is always true.

An undistorted guitar note makes a sine wave, the more distortion you get leads to the shape becoming more of a square wave.

Depending on the other instruments in the mix, either one of those could get "lost". A square wave will blend in more with drums & percussion instrument, while a sine wave may blend in more with a piano or violin.

Another relevant feature may be that a distorted guitar note lacks the attack/sustain that helps a guitar become distinguishable. Humans actually have a hard time identifying an instrument of the attack phase of the sound wave is erased.

Comment: Could you explain a "square" wave, an example of that other than distortion?  Also,  what or where is the "attack" phase of the sound wave,  does that refer to the absolute beginning of the wave, and whether a note starts as clean or distorted in attack?

Comment: Yes,  it is definitely not always true.   I'm trying to  get an idea regarding at what point losing the sound would happen.  For instance,  do certain other sounds/instruments have a natural distortion or square wave due to how the sound is produced,  say a drum, or different people's singing voice?  And is this what would cause the muddiness, when both are playing at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The more I think about it,  I think it is that the increase in distortion of the wave would eventually change the sound from a "pitch" or note (A,  G, E,  etc.)  to white noise,  lack of pitch,  and therefore be unheard amongst other true waves that equal a pitch.   I have not tried this,  and white noise has a sound, obviously,  even if played along with another sound. But perhaps if there are a certain number of other sounds,  the white noise becomes undetectable, unless it's volume is turned up much higher.   I may try this to see if the white noise sound disappears after several other sustained sounds are added.   Please add if I missed anything, assumed something incorrectly, or just repeated your answer using different terms.